# Append date column to rolling sum calculation of time series in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time-series, rolling-computation

Suppose I have the following time series data, `source`

```
+-----------+---+
|   Date    | A |
+-----------+---+
| 31-Dec-15 | 1 |
| 31-Dec-16 | 2 |
| 31-Dec-17 | 3 |
| 31-Dec-18 | 4 |
| 31-Dec-19 | 5 |
+-----------+---+
```

I am performing the following rolling calculation on `source` with `N = 2` and `N = 3`. R code:

```
for(i in (nrow(source)-(N-1)):1){A[i] <- sum(source$A[i:(i+(N-1))])}
output = data.frame(A)
print(output)
```

How do I integrate the date index into the above code so that

1. `N=2` output results in

```
+-----------+---+
|   Date    | A |
+-----------+---+
| 31-Dec-16 | 3 |
| 31-Dec-17 | 5 |
| 31-Dec-18 | 7 |
| 31-Dec-19 | 9 |
+-----------+---+
```

2. `N=3` output results in

```
+-----------+----+
|   Date    | A  |
+-----------+----+
| 31-Dec-17 |  6 |
| 31-Dec-18 |  9 |
| 31-Dec-19 | 12 |
+-----------+----+
```

My current code only outputs the `A` column, without the `Date` column. And I have to manually append the `Date` column after printing the `output`. My actual time series data is much longer than this and the rolling calculations are more complex so this is a simplified example.

Comment: You can use `rollsum(df1$A, 3)`

Comment: @akrun my actual rolling calculation code within the `for` code section is more complicated than what is in the above example. Hence, I would like to find a way to add the `Date` column without amending the `for` code section

Comment: Can't you just use `output <- data.frame(Date = source$Date[N:nrow(source)], A = A)`?

Answer (score 0):

Formalising @Alexlok suggestion:

```
for(i in (nrow(source)-(N-1)):1){A[i] <- sum(source$A[i:(i+(N-1))])}
output = data.frame(Date = source$Date[N:nrow(source)],A = A)
print(output)
```